# what kind of layout is best to choose?

Tags: android, android-layout

[form drawn in gimp][1]
the result should look something like this. What layout best to use? I realize with relative but scary cumbersome code, and using table having problems with height or width of some elements.

Comment: I can see that your user interface design isn't from Apple. but it will be a combination of several layouts nested http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Comment: I think it would be best to change it. If not relativelayout may be a good solution combined with linearlayouts

Comment: Combine relative layout with lineralayout that would be the best choice i did in one of my projects.

Comment: I am developing for a specific device, because of this strict requirements for the appearance. I've done similar menu with relative+linearlayout, but I try to use tablelayout, or it's bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

Parent - LinearLayout vertical

child views - relative layout or linearLayout depending on the complexity of each row. use relative layout for more complex rows.

I would also suggest you to create some reusable elements so that you can design your layout with ease.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view **RelativeLayout** will be good choice as it has very good options to achieve such arrangements.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) you can find details about this layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option here is to go with a `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayouts` as children.

But honestly, I think you have have too much information on just one View. You should try splitting this into different activities and create a "wizard like" experience.

Your current layout would most likely have issues rendering properly on devices with smaller screen.